# How do I Measure distance using php?

Tags: php

I should start of by saying that I'm still pretty green when it comes to PHP, so please be patient with me. I'm trying to figure out the distance between two latitudes and longitudes using php. I found a bunch of scripts online but, however when I try to test them I get the same distance no matter what latitudes and longitudes I use.  I'm sure it's something probably on my part, so I'll just post what I have so far.

```
$lat1 = "29.140762";
$lon1 = "-91.639243";

$lat2 = "29.136275";
$lon2 = "-91.635524";

function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);

    if ($unit == "K") {
        return ($miles * 1.609344);
    } else if ($unit == "N") {
        return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
    }
}

// Miles
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "m") . " miles<br><br>";

//Kilometers
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "k") . " kilometers<br><br>";

//Nautical miles
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "n") . " nautical miles";
```

Comment: *Thinks back to the distance formula from highschool math*

Comment: Have you tried printing out the value of `$unit` after running `strotupper()`.  I know it sounds dumb, but caveman debugging is pretty good figuring out issues like this.

Comment: @AlexLunix it's not the formula, the question is a little difficult to understand, but the problem is that he's getting miles back all the time instead of miles, km or nm.  Or at least that's what I think...

Comment: I suspect you're having a caching issue. Try hard refreshing(ctrl + R) the page after you edit it.

Comment: I tried the (ctrl + R)  No luck... I still get the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you've hard coded your inputs and are just changing the variables at the top of the page and expecting new results. Those variables don't do anything currently. Try the changes I've made below to your function calls, now the variables will be recognized.

```
// Miles
echo distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, "m") . " miles<br><br>";

//Kilometers
echo distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, "k") . " kilometers<br><br>";

//Nautical miles
echo distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, "n") . " nautical miles";
```

Comment: I'm glad we got it going for you.

Answer (score 0):

### NO it does not

Just tested it and outputs

```
262.67779380543 miles

422.73893139401 kilometers

228.10939614064 nautical miles
```

### Update

```
Here is another output when using 
// Miles
echo distance(35.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "m") . " miles<br><br>";

//Kilometers
echo distance(35.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "k") . " kilometers<br><br>";

//Nautical miles
echo distance(35.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "n") . " nautical miles";
```

> 460.32704312505 miles
>
> 740.82456489105 kilometers
>
> 399.7480042498 nautical miles

Comment: I don't think anyone is arguing that the conversions work. The OP is saying that if they change the inputs they will receive the same set of answers.

Comment: That's what I get every time....  I have tried to change the coordinates to a position that I know is a good distance and I still get the same output.

Comment: @Starx: I understand it does not. But that is what the OP is saying. Obviously it works for you and me, etc. Hence why i think it's a caching issue.

Comment: @JustinPetty, i test it mulitple times with many input, they are all differentt. How correct they are, i haven't checked that

Comment: @JustinPetty, remove the $lat1, $lat2 declaration at the top and try it again

Comment: @JustinPetty, clear the browser's history. It is **definately that**